# wwwroot directory is not copied to the tools\net6.0\any directory in a NuGet package [.NET6 + ASP.NET Core]

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild, nuget, .net-6.0

Just migrated to the new .NET6 preview.
And I have a problem with my NuGet package.
I have an ASP.NET Core web application which is a NuGet package.

- With .NET5 the `wwwroot` directory was being copied to the `tools\net5.0\any` folder.
- With .NET6 the `wwwroot` directory is not being copied to the `tools\net6.0\any` folder.

So my web application doesn't work now!

Question is; how to copy the `wwwroot` into the `tools\net6.0\any\wwwroot` folder in my *.nupkg file.

I'm using the following command to create NuGet package:

```sh
dotnet msbuild /t:pack /p:Configuration=Release /p:SourceLinkCreate=true
```

This my `project.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.3</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <ToolCommandName>dummy</ToolCommandName>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
    <AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
    <PreserveCompilationReferences>true</PreserveCompilationReferences>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    <PackageId>dummy</PackageId>
    <PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
  </PropertyGroup>
 
 
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Pages\**\*.*" Exclude="*.cs" />
    <Content Remove="Pages\**\*.js" />
    <Content Remove="Pages\**\*.css" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Components\**\*.js" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Components\**\*.css" />
    <Content Remove="Components\**\*.js" />
    <Content Remove="Components\**\*.css" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Localization\Resources\**\*.json" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Themes\Lepton\Layouts\Application\_Footer.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Localization\Resources\**\*.json" />
    <Content Remove="compilerconfig.json" />
    <Content Remove="compilerconfig.json.defaults" />
    <Content Remove="Properties\launchSettings.json" />
    <Content Remove="Themes\Lepton\Layouts\Application\_Footer.cshtml" />
    <None Include="compilerconfig.json" />
    <None Include="Properties\launchSettings.json" />
    
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Logs\**" />
    <Content Remove="Logs\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Logs\**" />
    <None Remove="Logs\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
 

</Project>
```

[image]

Comment: I am facing this issue, did you get any resolution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same problem after upgrading from .NET5 to .NET6.. I switched to dotnet publish instead of dotnet build. Dotnet publish does include the wwwroot.

Extra tip: Take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ccr) to update your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am suffering from the same problem, I know what I am suggesting isn't a fix and is more of a temporary workaround, however, the only way I have found so far is by copying my `wwwroot` folder to my `bin/Release/net6.0` folder.

Hopefully someone is able to reply with a proper fix to this issue.

Comment: have you ever found a proper solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am still just copying `wwwroot` into the `bin/Release/net6.0` folder

Answer (score 0):

StaticWebAssetsEnabled false solved it for me

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    <PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
    <ToolCommandName>dotnet-something</ToolCommandName>
    <PackageOutputPath>../nupkg</PackageOutputPath>
    <StaticWebAssetsEnabled>false</StaticWebAssetsEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
```